# Mage registry key "original_include_path" already exists

Tags: php, magento, mage

I am expericing an error with my magento 1.3 site. Whenever I try to add or duplicate a product, I recive the following error message (Mage registry key "original_include_path" already exists). This issue started after I retifed an issue with our site resulting from functions being deprecated in php 5.3 (As per the advice here:http://www.geekieblog.com/2011/03/magento-1-3-x-environment-won%E2%80%99t-run-on-php-5-3/). I have tried to manally unregister this key by calling the unregister function from mage.php on it. However, I get the following error when I try to do that: "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Mage in /home/pipesand/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 61"

Thanks,